# Passing string between two forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem in passing a string value between two forms.

First I created public string `sanacode` which I assign the value passed in `form 2`

**Form 1 code**

```
AnalysisEdit ae = new AnalysisEdit();
int Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
ae.sanacode = dataGridView1[0, Row].Value.ToString();
ae.Show();
```

**Form 2 constructor code**

```
public AnalysisEdit()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show(sanacode,);
}
```

it shows me nothing

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Can you make sure `ae.sanacode = dataGridView1[0, Row].Value.ToString();` is pulling back any value? Also post more code of your `AnalysisEdit` form or you are going to end up with everyone posting to make a property or variable. You may have already done this.

Answer (score 2):

Change you constructor from

```
public AnalysisEdit()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   MessageBox.Show(sanacode);
}
```

to

```
public AnalysisEdit(string sanacode)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show(sanacode);
}
```

form call

```
int Row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
AnalysisEdit ae = new AnalysisEdit(dataGridView1[0, Row].Value.ToString());    
ae.Show();
```

Comment: it tells me that i must have a constructor with empty parameter

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not calling things in the correct order. The form 2 constructor code will be called on line 1 of the form code, or `AnalysisEdit ae = new AnalysisEdit();` However, this is before the assignment that takes place on line 3: `ae.sanacode = dataGridView1[0, Row].Value.ToString();`  So when you show the messagebox in the form 2 constructor, `sanacode` has not yet been assigned to.

There are two ways to fix this. Firstly, you can pass the value in via the constructor as per @kostas ch.'s answer, or you can override the form's `OnShown` event in form 2:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(sanacode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't put your code

```
MessageBox.Show(sanacode,);
```

in the constructor. I would use the "Load"-Event.
If you use the "Load"-Event your MessageBox will Show, when you use

```
ae.Show();
```

Like this

```
private void AnalysisEdit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sanacode);
    }
```

Comment: the idea to use messagebox is to make sure that the string is passed correctly what i want exactly is to pass string from datagrid in form 1 to be used in form 2

Comment: Even if I also think that the other solutions are better, my code does exactly what you just described. It will take a string that you apply to sanacode in Form1 and shows it after you Load Form2

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you'd like some ideas for the various ways to pass data between forms. I have written two blog posts on the subject:

http://geek-goddess-bonnie.blogspot.com/2011/01/passing-data-between-forms.html

http://geek-goddess-bonnie.blogspot.com/2012/12/passing-data-between-forms-redux_31.html

Answer (score -1):

You could temporarily add `MessageBox.Show()` to your setter:

```
// In Form2
public sanacode
{
  set
  {
    _sanacode = value;
    MessageBox.Show(_sanacode);
  }

  get
  {
    return _sanacode;
  }
}
```